# I am tryin to protect my admin link, ButI am catching below error

Tags: angular, authentication, admin

Argument of type '(user: any) => AngularFireObject | Observable' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput'.ts(2345)
Argument of type '(user: any) => AngularFireObject | Observable' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput'.
Type 'AngularFireObject | Observable' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.
Type 'AngularFireObject' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.ts(2345)
Below us my code

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/internal/Observable";
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, RouterLink, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
import { switchMap, of } from "rxjs";
import { UserService } from "./user.service";
import { AppUser } from "./Models/app-user";



@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) 

export class AuthService {
  [x: string]: any;
  user$: Observable<firebase.User|any> ;

  constructor(private afAuth:AngularFireAuth, private router:Router,private  route: ActivatedRoute,
    private userService: UserService) {
    this.user$ = afAuth.authState;
   }
  login() {
    let returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl') || '/';
    localStorage.setItem('returnUrl',returnUrl);
    this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(new GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
  logout(){
    this.afAuth.signOut();
  }
  isLoggedin(state:RouterStateSnapshot,route:RouterStateSnapshot){
    this.user$?.subscribe(user =>{
      if(user) return true;

      this.router.navigate(['/login'],{queryParams:{returnUrl:state.url}});
      return false;
    })
  }
  getAppUser(): Observable<AppUser> {
    return this.user$.pipe(
      switchMap((user) =>{
        if (user) {
          return this.userService.get(user.uid);
        }
        return of(null);
      })
    );
  }
  
}
```

and the eror is coming from

```
getAppUser(): Observable<AppUser> {
    return this.user$.pipe(
      switchMap((user) =>{
        if (user) {
          return this.userService.get(user.uid);
        }
        return of(null);
      })
    );
  }
```

This is my user.servie.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { AppUser } from './Models/app-user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private db : AngularFireDatabase) { }
  save(user: firebase.User){
    this.db.object('/user/'+user.uid).update({
      name: user.displayName,
      email:user.email
    });
  }
  get(uid:String):AngularFireObject <AppUser>{
    return this.db.object('/user/'+uid);
  }
}
```

Please help me for this

Comment: Can you show the implementation for `this.userService.get(user.uid)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Working with AngularFireObject and switchMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473504/working-with-angularfireobject-and-switchmap)

Comment: yes but now navebar/navebar.component.ts:23:12 - error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

23     afauth.getAppUser().subscribe(appUser => this.appUser = appUser)}
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  auth.service.ts:39:14
    39   getAppUser(uid: string): Observable<AppUser> {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
    An argument for 'uid' was not provided.

Comment: That is another question which not related to current problem. If you read your code and the error message, you didn't provide the uid value to the `getAppUser` method. `afauth.getAppUser(/* Provide uid here */).subscribe(...)`

Comment: I add uid values but there is a error in my console, I pass ' ', '/' and '/home' for seveal tiles but thereis a error inmy console now, main.ts:11 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'object')